A problem that is stumping our whole section in Basic Calculus
We have an assignment that we're supposed to pass by Monday, and all seems to be well until this problem showed up.
$\int 9x \sin (x^3)dx$
We're only 2 lessons in to Integrals and have only recently covered u-substitution. Here is the current state of the solution our classmates have made. It is not complete as we're currently stuck on the next step we have to take.
$$\int 9x \sin (x^3)dx \\u = x^3 \\ du = 3x^2dx\\dx = \frac{du}{3x^2}\\\int 9x \sin(u)\frac{du}{3x^2} = \int \frac{9x}{3x^2} \sin(u)du=\int \frac{3}{x} \sin(u)du$$
Now this part is completely unnecessary and subjective but the teacher has been known to give out problems that require lessons we have not yet tackled.
Thank you in advance.

Possibly a typo, and the intended integrand was $x \sin(x^{\color{red}2})$ or $x^{\color{red}{2}} \sin(x^3)$? You need special functions for the given expression's antiderivative.

Have you checked with your teacher that there isn't a mistake?

@TobySaunders-A'Court well, we tried to get the integral of 3/x to get 3ln|x| but one of us said it isn't possible as we're integrating with respect to u.

I agree with @user170231 as it has to be a typo. It happens - just bring it up with the instructor. Also, when you change variables, everything has to be written in the new variable - no mix and match.

@ZoeAllen unfortunately not since we didn't know if the given problem had an error. But we're speculating that the problem instead had 9x^2 or sin(x^2) as user170231 pointed out

Differentiate $\cos(x^2)$ to get something which "suitably matches" the Question with typo. Without typo , the Integral is well beyond the "2 lessons in to Integrals" level !

If the problem were $\int_{}^{}9x^{2}sin(x^{3})dx$ instead, the substitution $u=\cos(x^{3})$ works
